# Creating a zip arhcive in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, zip

i am new to Node.JS and i want to do search in a folder for a specific string and add all the files that are found in a zip archive.
Example : I have the string "house" and in a folder i have house_1.txt house_2.txt and car.The archive must contain house_1.txt , house_2.txt. I searched something on Google but i couldn't do it .

Comment: Can you please paste the code what you have tried so far? Also tell us at which step you get stucked. Please also explain which version of `nodejs` do you use and what framework if any.

Comment: no framework, version 8.12.0.Basically now i only return house.txt if exist . I don't know how to search file names to caontain house.Sorry if i didn;t explained very good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code doesn't pretend to be super fast, since it is synchronous, but it works.

```
const JSZip = require("jszip");
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const isDirectory = (filePath) => fs.statSync(filePath).isDirectory();

const findFiles = (dir, fileNames, recursive = false) => {
  const foundFiles = [];

  fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach(file => {
    const filePath = path.join(dir, file);

    if(recursive && isDirectory(filePath)) {
      foundFiles.push(...findFiles(filePath, fileNames, true));

    } else if(fileNames.includes(file)){
      foundFiles.push(filePath);
    }
  });

  return foundFiles;
};

const getFileName = filePath => filePath.indexOf("/") !== -1 ?
    filePath.substr(filePath.lastIndexOf("/")) : filePath;

const zipFiles = (filePaths, zipPath) => {
  const zip = new JSZip();
  filePaths.forEach(filePath => {
    const fileName = getFileName(filePath) + "_" + Date.now();
    const content = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
    zip.file(fileName, content);
  });

  zip.generateNodeStream({type: 'nodebuffer', streamFiles: true})
      .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(zipPath))
      .on('finish', () => console.log(`${zipPath} has been created.`));
};

const filesDir = `${__dirname}/../resources`;
zipFiles(findFiles(filesDir, ["test1.txt"], true), `${filesDir}/out.zip`);
```